# Horizontal Scrollable Textview inside ListView Items

Tags: android, listview, textview, scrollview

I'm having a TextView (the second one) inside my ListView Items. The User should be able to scroll horizontally through it, when the text in side it does not fit in the desired maxHeight (250dp). I tried it with HorizontalScrollView, but does not seem to work. Anyone having a solution for my problem? (The items are stylized as cards, so the hierarchy might seem odd)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:background="@drawable/card_background_selector"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="255dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="1248$"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/answer"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:maxWidth="250dp"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Some looooooooooooooooooooooooooooong Text"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a scroll to your TextView without using ScrollView, You can add

`android:scrollbars = "Horizontal"` to your TextView and then in you code  add

```
yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this would be the right way of doing this.But following two methods worked for me for the same requirement.

1. Give sufficiently large width, for example, you can have 3000dp value.

Or

2. Dynamically change the width of the textView according to the length of the string you might going to fill it.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams widthHeightParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(20,2000);
mTextView.setLayoutParams(widthHeightParams);
```

Give it a try

Comment: 1. You mean giving the text view such a large width? Unfortunately it does not work :( 
2.  I can't do that, because the view would expand into my other view (image view).